# alamofire, downloading multiple images

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Im attempting to download an image from a url and make it the tableviewcell image for each cell in the table view. The program downloads the contents of each cell and then uses alamofire to download the image according to the id value passed in from the server.

When i use the code below, the first image is always the same as the second and i cannot figure out why, when I add more cells they work perfectly. I only just started using alamofire today, so im possibly missing something obvious, sorry in advance if thats the case.

```
     for result in resultsAsArray {

                if let resultDict = result as? NSDictionary {

                    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "identifer")
                    cell.textLabel?.text = resultDict.objectForKey("name") as? String

                    let id = (resultDict.objectForKey("productId") as! String).toInt()!
                    cell.tag = id

                    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

                    let image = request(.GET,
                        "http://www.website.com/\(id).png").response() {

                        (_, _, data, _) in

                            println("loading image for \(id)")

                            let image = UIImage(data: data! as NSData)
                            cell.imageView!.image = image

                    }

                    products.append(cell)

                    (view.viewWithTag(1) as! UITableView).reloadData()

                }

            }
```

Comment: Also when i delete all the images from my server, they are still being loaded in the app - possibly the issue is server side?

Comment: As an aside, this whole approach is backwards. You should not be building an array of cells with images. The only place you should be instantiating cells is in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and you should be dequeueing cells, not instantiating your own. And usually people will use lazy loading of images, not loading all of the images for the whole table (reloading the table for each).

Comment: okay, thank you, im always trying to make the code as "correct" as possible so ill be making those changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue is server side, when i change the images they are not being changed on the server instantly - alamofire is working fine

- i originally made the first cell image the image that should be for number 2, after i moved it, alamofire had cached it so it was always displaying the image intended for number 2